# Use SPARQL and Dbpedia to query for cities within a given radius based on long and lat

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've been trying to use DBpedia and SPARQL to get cities based on a geo location.

E.g., `http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin` has the properties

```
geo:lat: 52.516666 (xsd:float)
geo:long: 13.383333 (xsd:float)
```

and I want to query cities based on location and within a given radius.
E.g.,  I want to find cities within 10km of lat: 51.5033640 and long: -0.1276250

I know this gives me cities --

```
SELECT ?city WHERE {      ?city rdf:type dbo:City    }
```

-- but I don't how to use filter in order to filter out based on radius. Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Virtuoso GeoSpatial functions `bif:st_intersects` and `bif:st_point`:

Either with the geometry object (no cities for your London coordinates, change to `dbo:Place` to see that there other objects around London):

```sql
SELECT  * { 
 ?city a dbo:City ;
       geo:geometry ?geo
 FILTER ( bif:st_intersects( ?geo, bif:st_point (-0.1276250, 51.5033640), 10))
}
```

Or with lat/long:

```sql
SELECT * { 
 ?city a dbo:City ;
       geo:lat ?lat ;
       geo:long ?long .
 FILTER ( bif:st_intersects( bif:st_point (?long, ?lat), bif:st_point (-0.1276250, 51.5033640), 10))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would never have figured it out! - Have a great day!